# Odoo - How to update field value from another module

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to make a module to manage travel leaves for employees.

What I need to do is adding extra float field in hr.employee module of 'available_tickets' . To be allocated from other module named "travel_request". How to do this?
Here's my code:

```
class travel_request(osv.osv):

    _name = 'travel.request'

    _columns = {

        'no_tickets': fields.float('Number of Tickets'),

     }

class hr_employee(osv.osv):
_inherit="hr.employee"


def _get_tickets(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    tickets_obj = self.pool.get('travel.request')
    tickets_ids = self.pool.get('travel.request').search(cr, uid, [('user_id', '=', uid), ('state', '=', 'validate')])
    for t_id in tickets_ids :
        emp_ticket = tickets_obj.browse(cr, uid, t_id, context=context)

    res['available_tickets'] = emp_ticket.no_tickets
    return res    


_columns = {
    'available_tickets': fields.function(_get_tickets, string='Available Tickets', type="float", store=True),
}
```

I tried also this method:

```
def _get_tickets(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    tickets_obj = self.pool.get('travel.request')
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        tickets_ids = tickets_obj.search(cr, uid, [('user_id', '=', uid), ('state', '=', 'validate')], ids, context=None)
        emp_ticket = tickets_obj.browse(cr, uid, tickets_ids[0], context=None )
        res['available_tickets'] = emp_ticket.no_tickets        
    return res
```

But nothing happened, I don't know what is wrong.. can anyone help me to fix it

Here's the error message:

```
2016-02-16 13:29:14,549 27608 ERROR test2_travel openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 944, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/hr_holidays/hr_holidays.py", line 494, in create
    return super(hr_employee, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/hr/hr.py", line 285, in create
    employee_id = super(hr_employee, self).create(cr, uid, data, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 381, in create
    thread_id = super(mail_thread, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 372, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4094, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 508, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4279, in _create
    result += self._columns[field].set(cr, self, id_new, field, vals[field], user, rel_context) or []
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1486, in set
    self._fnct_inv(obj, cr, user, id, name, value, self._fnct_inv_arg, context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/hr/hr.py", line 186, in _set_image
    return self.write(cr, uid, [id], {'image': tools.image_resize_image_big(value)}, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/addons/mail/mail_thread.py", line 432, in write
    result = super(mail_thread, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 3789, in write
    self._write(old_vals)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 592, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4037, in _write
    cr, user, todo, fields_to_recompute, context)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4453, in _store_set_values
    cr.execute(query, (column._symbol_set[1](value), id))
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 158, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo8/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 234, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "available_tickets"
LINE 1: ...ployee" SET "available_tickets"='5.00' WHERE id = 'available...
```

Comment: you need change value *on fly*? I mean in GUI?

Comment: yes, and sorry I didn't define the field as function.. I've updated it in the question

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple issues.

## 1. Your error message

The error message `DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "available_tickets"` points at your error. Your computed field implementation returns a `dict` with `"available_tickets"` as the key instead of the employee IDs. So when the system tries to update the database it fails to find an employee record with ID `"available_tickets"`.

The problem lies is in `get_tickets()`:

```python
res['available_tickets'] = emp_ticket.no_tickets
```

You need to iterate over the employee `ids` that are passed to `get_tickets()` and return a result `res` that looks like this:

```python
{
  1: 3.0,  # 3 `available_tickets` for employee ID 1
  2: 4.0,  # 4 `available_tickets` for employee ID 2
  ...
}
```

So in `get_tickets()` you should have something like this:

```python
res[emp.id] = <computed number of tickets> # emp = hr.employee record!
```

Please a look at the documentation for writing computed fields ([old API](https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/server/03_module_dev_02/#functional-fields), [new API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#field-computed)), or examples in the official Odoo modules for inspiration.

## 2. Your computed field logic

Your current (draft?) implementation for the `get_tickets()` makes little sense:

- it should have a main loop over the requested `hr.employee` IDs. This is important because Odoo computed fields are computed in batch by the system.
- it should presumably not depend on the current user to compute the result. Currently you're searching for the `travel.requests` of the current user via this domain `('user_id', '=', uid)`. This means you're looking at the `travel.requests` of the *user who is viewing or modifying the employee*, not the user *of that employee*. This is where the `ids` variable should be used ; to `browse` the employees for whom you are computing values, and then search the appropriate `travel.request`.
- if you are storing the computed value (`store=True`), you need proper recomputing triggers, otherwise the stored value will not change when you modify/add `travel.request`. In the new API this is done with the `@api.depends`, and in the old API by passing a `store` dictionary, as explained in the documentation.

Reading the documentation and the source code of official addons is really the best way to learn about Odoo computed fields.

Comment: dear developer, I completely agree with you. Your answer is the most correct, complete and informative. Therefore my answer does not make sense. Good luck in development ;)